# Using `Fixed Width` in Questions and Answers

Tags: discussion, formatting

Recently someone edited one of my posts (OK, maybe not ***that*** recently), and mentioned (as the reason for the edit) that it is not appropriate to use **`Fixed Width`** to highlight text in posts.

I haven't seen this mentioned in any FAQ or Meta post. Is this really true?

I have searched, and I can't seem to find the post that was edited (I can't remember if it was a Question or an Answer). It could have easily been on another SE site, but I have done some searching around and I still can't find it.

I suppose it could have actually been a Suggested-edit that was later rejected by a moderator, which would explain why I can't find it, but it's just a guess, and I have no way to know that.

Also, while I'm asking, is there a way to see a list of all the Questions and Answers that have been edited (edits and suggested edits) by others?

Comment: [Changes to your posts by others are in the "Responses" tab of your user profile](http://superuser.com/users/144147/kevin-fegan?tab=responses&sort=revisions).

Comment: Formatting is mostly a personal preference, and suggested edits with only minor formatting changes are usually rejected as *too minor*. Objective criteria which is best could be readability concerns (in this case) and how the [corresponding HTML elements are defined and usually interpreted](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element).

Comment: It's `quite` possible that it was `me` who made that `edit`.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - It could be, but I looked on both SU and SO, and I don't see the question/answer in my profile under **Responses**. On SU I see only 4 **Revisions** but none for that reason. At the time I saw the edit, I let it stand. Since it is now gone, I can only guess that it was a ***Suggested-edit*** from someone with less than 2000 Rep, which was then rejected by the system or someone else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The backticks (`) are a [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) shortcut for what will later be rendered as `<code>` in HTML. Needless to say that this tag should be used to highlight actual code (or commands), not arbitrary words.

To highlight keywords, the `<em>` tag should be used. This again will often be displayed as italics, so you get the same result by wrapping text with `<i>` tags.

From the Chicago Manual of Style (chapter 7.47):

> Use italics for emphasis only as an occasional adjunct to efficient sentence structure. Overused, italics quickly lose their force. Seldom should as much as a sentence be italicized for emphasis, and never a whole passage.

This is just general advice. Briefly looking over your posts, I don't even think that's relevant for you—but it might be for others. There's a certain trend where people use `code` for highlighting `everything` that could be remotely `important`.

See also: [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right)

Comment: Thanks, I try to reserve its use for highlighting things like variable names, menu choices, tab choices, *"thangs to click on"* while describing how to navigate through various screens on software, and actual code.